# Shell Script to find difference between two values

Tags: linux, performance, bash, shell

I Need find difference between `"WAM1"` and `"WAM2"` in below `/var/log/messages`

```
2013-07-09T02:20:18.535639Z user.info WbAppMg WAM1
2013-07-09T02:20:21.817372Z user.info sam SAM  
2013-07-09T02:20:21.818442Z user.info sam SAM  
2013-07-09T02:20:22.746751Z user.info WbAppMg WAM2
2013-07-09T02:20:23.846636Z user.info sam SAM  
2013-07-09T02:20:24.851727Z user.info sam SAM
```

For Below program gives some error

```
#!/bin/bash

file="/var/log/messages"
apploaded="WAM1"
appcreated="WAM2"
timepattern="{s/.*T[0-9]*:[0-9]*:\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\)Z.*/\1/g;p}"
stop=`sed -n /$apploaded/$timepattern $file`
start=`sed -n /$appcreated/$timepattern $file`
delta=$(awk "BEGIN{print $stop-$start}")
echo Delta=$delta
```

output like

```
(WAM2-WAM1) = (22.746751-18.535639) = 4.211112 (Expected Output)
Delta== 4.211112
```

Comment: What happens if there are two WAM1 entries in a row, or two WAM2 entries in a row?  Presumably, you could suffer from WAM1 at 2013-12-31T23:59:59.012345 and WAM2 at 2014-01-01T00:00:03.987654, so you have to deal with dates wrapping around minutes, hours, days, months, years. Since your time zone is Zulu time (UTC, aka GMT), you don't have to worry about switches between winter and summer (standard and daylight saving) time; phew!

Comment: use only seconds(hours not required) difference between the values 2013-07-09T02:20:18.535639Z user.info WbAppMg WAM1 in this only 18.535639Z is enough for us take difference

Comment: if you have access to gawk, you could code the whole thing in 1 script and use the mktime() function (and related techniques) to calc the difference. Time calcs in awk/gawk shouldn't be hard to find searching here on S.O. (otherwise, good post, sample data, example output and ... gasp some code!).. Good luck.

Comment: timepattern = awk '/\<WAM\>/ {split($1, a, ":"); print a[2] ":" a[3]}' also other method

Comment: @Santosh - What happens when the seconds wrap around: Start is `11:20:58` and end is `11:21:05`?

Comment: @David W. i bother only 18.535639Z data in below data                        2013-07-09T02:20:18.535639Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something to get you started:

```
awk '
  /WAM1/{ split($1,start,/[:Z]/); wam1[++i]=start[3] }
  /WAM2/{ split($1,stop,/[:Z]/); wam2[++j]=stop[3] }
  END   { len=i>j?i:j; for(;x<len;) print "Delta "++x" = "wam2[x]-wam1[x] }
' log
```

Please note that might not be your final solution but is something to get your stared. This code **assumes** that the Year, month, day, hour and minutes are same and the difference is calculated only at seconds level. This should work if thats your true case.

This will also work if you have several lines of WAM1 and WAM2 since we use an array to keep track of them. Delta printed at the end will print a number that would be a reference to which incident of WAM1 and WAM2 was subtracted. However there is an assumption made here that both should exist.

If you need to make a more generic script, I would recommend using `awk's  mktime()` function. The code would be more but will serve useful for plethora of cases.

**Output**:

```
$ cat log
2013-07-09T02:20:18.535639Z user.info WbAppMg WAM1
2013-07-09T02:20:21.817372Z user.info sam SAM  
2013-07-09T02:20:21.818442Z user.info sam SAM  
2013-07-09T02:20:22.746751Z user.info WbAppMg WAM2
2013-07-09T02:20:23.846636Z user.info sam SAM  
2013-07-09T02:20:24.851727Z user.info sam SAM  
2013-07-09T02:20:18.535639Z user.info WbAppMg WAM1
2013-07-09T02:20:21.817372Z user.info sam SAM
2013-07-09T02:20:21.818442Z user.info sam SAM
2013-07-09T02:20:22.746751Z user.info WbAppMg WAM2
2013-07-09T02:20:23.846636Z user.info sam SAM
2013-07-09T02:20:24.851727Z user.info sam SAM
2013-07-09T02:20:18.535639Z user.info WbAppMg WAM1
2013-07-09T02:20:21.817372Z user.info sam SAM
2013-07-09T02:20:21.818442Z user.info sam SAM
2013-07-09T02:20:22.746751Z user.info WbAppMg WAM2
2013-07-09T02:20:23.846636Z user.info sam SAM
2013-07-09T02:20:24.851727Z user.info sam SAM
2013-07-09T02:20:18.535639Z user.info WbAppMg WAM1
2013-07-09T02:20:21.817372Z user.info sam SAM
2013-07-09T02:20:21.818442Z user.info sam SAM
2013-07-09T02:20:22.746751Z user.info WbAppMg WAM2
2013-07-09T02:20:23.846636Z user.info sam SAM
2013-07-09T02:20:24.851727Z user.info sam SAM
<!-->

$ awk '
/WAM1/{ split($1,start,/[:Z]/); wam1[++i]=start[3] }
/WAM2/{ split($1,stop,/[:Z]/); wam2[++j]=stop[3] }
END   { len=i>j?i:j; for(;x<len;) print "Delta "++x" = "wam2[x]-wam1[x] }' log
Delta 1 = 4.21111
Delta 2 = 4.21111
Delta 3 = 4.21111
Delta 4 = 4.21111
```

Comment: What happens if the start time is `2013-07-09T02:20:58` and the end time is `2013-07-09T02:21:04`?

Comment: @DavidW. Like I said `This code assumes that the Year, month, day, hour and minutes are same and the difference is calculated only at seconds level`

Comment: Delta 1 = 0
Delta 2 = 0
Delta 3 = 0
Delta 4 = 0

Comment: @Santosh Hmm, is your input data different that the sample data provided above?

Comment: WAM2-WAM1 need yes provided in example log

Comment: I used your sample data for my tests which are shown above (so it works for your sample data). Feel free to modify the script for your needs.

Comment: awk '
  /WAM APP CREATED WINDOW/{ split($1,start,/[:Z]/); wam3[i++]=start[3] }
  /WAM APPLOADED/{ split($1,stop,/[:Z]/); wam4[j++]=stop[3] }
  END   { len=2; for(;x<len;x++) print "Delta = "wam4[x]-wam3[x] }
' /var/log/messages
output I am getting is                                          Delta = 0 (Its error above Log)
Delta = 0.906095   Need your suggestion on this ???

Answer (score 1):

I would use a loop to look for the lines you want. The reason is simple. It will allow you to handle what to do if you have multiple `WAM1` and `WAM2` entries. The following is assuming that there's only a single `WAM1` and `WAM2`, and that `WAM1` comes before `WAM2`.

Also note that this is BSD and not GNU date command. The GNU date command works differently, but I have a Mac in front of me and not a Linux box.

I'm looking for the WAM lines and storing them in `$wam1` and `$wam2` Once I loop through the whole file, I can then pull out the timestamp (which I'm doing with `sed`. Next, I use the `date` command to convert the dates from the given timestamp into seconds since January 1, 1970. Once the seconds are converted, I can subtract the end time from the start:

```
while read line
do
    if [[ $line == *WAM1 ]]
    then
        wam1="$line"
    fi
    if [[ $line == *WAM2 ]]
    then
        wam2="$line"
    fi
done < logfile.txt

timestart=$(sed 's/\.[0-9][0-9]*Z .*//' <<<"$wam1")
timeend=$(sed 's/\.[0-9][0-9]*Z .*//' <<<"$wam2")

start_seconds=$(date -j -f%FT%H:%M:%S +%s $timestart)
end_seconds=$(date -j -f%FT%H:%M:%S +%s $timeend)

((total_time=$end_seconds - $start_seconds))
echo "Total Time = $total_time seconds"
```

---

#### Linux/GNU

I just tested this on Linux/GNU, and this works:

```
while read line
do
    if [[ $line == *WAM1 ]]
    then
        wam1="$line"
    fi
    if [[ $line == *WAM2 ]]
    then
        wam2="$line"
    fi
done < logfile.txt

timestart=$(sed 's/\.[0-9][0-9]*Z .*//' <<<"$wam1")
timeend=$(sed 's/\.[0-9][0-9]*Z .*//' <<<"$wam2")

start_seconds=$(date --date="$timestart" +%s)
end_seconds=$(date --date="$timeend" +%s)

((total_time=$end_seconds - $start_seconds))
echo "Total Time = $total_time seconds"
```

Comment: What do you mean? This is a script, and there's no _compilation_. Is it with the lines that run the `date` command? I mentioned that Linux and GNU has different date utilities and their parameters will be different. This is for BSD and Mac. The `-j` parameter is the format my `$timestart` is in. The `+%s` is the format you want it in. I'll see if I can do this on Linux.

Comment: @Santosh - I added a Linux/GNU version

Answer (score 1):

Reading through your comments it appears that you only want difference between seconds values.

I believe awk can do all this. Consider this script:

```
awk '$NF ~ /^WAM[12]$/ { 
   match($1, /[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9]+Z$/)
   a[c++] = substr($1, RSTART, RLENGTH-1)
}
END {
   print a[1]-a[0]
}' logFile
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
4.21111
```